# mathematical operations in binding wpf

Tags: wpf

I have two text boxes

```
<TextBox Name="txtVal1" Text="{Binding Value1}" />
<TextBox Name="txtVal2" Text="{Binding Value2}" />
```

When I enter some values to these text boxes, I need to show the sum of those values (Value1 + Value2) in a separate text box.

And in the same manner , I have a data grid also. I need to show the sum in a separate column

```
<DataGrid>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 1" Binding="{Binding Value1}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value 2" Binding="{Binding Value1}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sum"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How do I do this task using data binding.

Comment: you can use MultiValueConverter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MultiValueConverter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx